# Is there a reference point or repository where I can find common design pattern implementations in MS .Net framework?

Tags: .net, design-patterns

Basically, I just want to see the design patterns in action in the MS .Net framework itself. For e.g. we can look at the stream classes and see how MS implemented the decorator pattern. Is there a way to find the other patterns in action as well? Has it been documented anywhere? People talk a lot about seeing patterns, I'm curious whether somebody has observed and cataloged these patterns in .Net framework itself.

Comment: A very good resource on design patterns is http://www.dofactory.com/Default.aspx. They also go into if a pattern is used in .net and where.

Comment: dofactory talks about how to implement a pattern in .net language. I'm looking for how and where Microsoft implemented these patterns in the .Net framework.

Answer (score 2):

First hit from google...

[MSDN Magazine, design patterns you are already using in .Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188707.aspx)

Comment: +1 Already found it :). I am looking for something more exhaustive.